# Using Static HTML instead of the `home_url()` WP function

Tags: functions, links, home-url

When I add links to pages in a custom WordPress theme I use the following function:

`href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/contact-page' ));?>"`

If I don't use the `home_ur()` function, but the following code, it still works:

`href="./contact-page"`

I'm currently only doing this on a localhost (MAMP) set up.

Is there any reason why I must use the `home_ur()` function instead of just the HTML code, which will be quicker to type, and obviously quicker for the server/browser to process?

Emily.

Comment: You shouldn't hard code URLs like that, instead you should use a nav menu, or refer to the pages post ID with `get_permalink`. Avoid hardcoded magic values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
href="./contact-page"
```

- if you're on the homepage (`/`) this will become: `/contact-page`
- if you're on another page named foo (`/foo/`) this will become `/foo/contact-page`

This is due to `./` being a relative path. To avoid struggles like this, the method via `home_url()` is preferred because it creates absolute links/paths that will work from anywhere you call it.

**Note:**

You could use `href="/contact-page"` which is relative as well, but only to the domain and not the current page. However I can't tell you why WP rather uses and stores absolute URLs.